# How many times has a user run my app?

Tags: java, android

I am making a android application right now in Java.

- Can I know *how many times my application has been run in a day?*

Cos if I put a counter in the main method, it will be equal to 1 after each new start. If I use the **SharedPreference** to count, the counter will not be equal to 1 the NEXT day. I want it so that every new day the counter will be equal to 1, but if the day is still the same, the counter will continue to increase. (If user runs the application a third time, the counter will be equal to 3).

I am implying that I have to use DATA, but I have no idea how.

Comment: First launch: no value exists -> create. Next for the 
2...n launches: read the value and say "++" and put it back in the prefs as well. ;) That's all.

Comment: There are [Android app analytics packages](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20app%20analytics) that exist to provide this, and other feedback. But note that I will hate you and your app if you use such tools.

Comment: "egrish" <- that's really funny :D

Answer (score 1):

you can use Calendar to see if you are in today or not. then you can use a counter inside your first activity to count number of app's start. and you can store this info into database.